# Porque é que não consigo visualizar o Form1.cs

Tags: c#

Criei um `tableLayoutPanel` e posteriormente queria colocar um `Panel` em cada célula do `tableLayoutPanel`.

Fiz o seguinte código e quando compilo, funciona.

```
Panel[,] panels = new Panel[tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount+1, tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount+1];
for (int i = 1; i <= tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount; i++) {
    columns = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; j++) {
        panels[i, j] = new Panel() {
            BackColor = Color.AliceBlue,
            Margin = new Padding(0),
        };
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panels[i, j], i - 1, j - 1);
        columns++;
        counter++;
    }
    rows++;
}
Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
```

Porque é que deixo de conseguir aceder ao Design quando tenho este código? O erro que aparece é o seguinte:

> "The designer cannot process the code at line 445 (...) The code
>   within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer
>   and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try
>   opening the designer again."

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. @João, poderia [edit] sua pergunta e esclarecer a parte "deixo de conseguir aceder ao Design", ficou confuso. Obrigado.

Comment: Já editei. Não consigo ver a parte "visual" do programa. O ficheiro Form1.cs[Design].

Comment: @JoãoLopes onde você pôs esse código? Qual método e em qual arquivo?

Comment: Coloquei o código no Form1.Designer.cs. Ok, já percebi... É aqui que está o problema... Não posso colocar aqui o codigo

Answer (score 0):

Você está codificando no arquivo `.design.cs` em vez de codificar no code behind, os arquivos de design são gerados e mantidos pelo `Visual Studio` e você não deveria modifica-los.